# In Eclipse's Console view (for debug consoles), how to modify the size of the view dedicated to the output and command input

Tags: eclipse, console

In Eclipse's Console view, when I run a PyDev debug launcher, I found the view was hard-split vertically into two panes. The top pane contained the stderr/stdout output, while the bottom pane permitted me to type in any stdin I needed (at the >>> prompt).

However, I didn't like the sizing of these two panes and was hoping for some sort of splitter bar to adjust, but no such splitter bar was to be found.

Any thoughts on how to work around this?

[image: Debug Console with no adjustable splitter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploring the little icons within the console view, I found this icon offered a "**Set Console Height**" option.

[image]

It then offered a dialog for you to type in a percentage of one pane to the other.

Seems a little rough, but it'll do for now...